# Help removing a link with hook_link_alter in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need some help with the syntax of hook_link_alter . My code is

```
function modulename_link_alter(&$links, &$node, $comment = null){
  foreach($links as $module=>$link){
    if (isset($links['link_id'])) {
    unset($links['link_id']);
    }
  }
}
```

This does not remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function mymodule_link_alter(&$links, $node) {
  foreach ($links as $module => $link) {
    if (strstr($module, 'blog')) {
      unset($links[$module]);
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `blog` with where ever you need it to remove

Answer (score 0):

It can be very simple, put this in a custom module.  It is good practice to have your own module dedicated to site tweaks.

```
function mycustomsitemodule_link_alter(&links, $node) {
   unset($links['link_id_to_unset']);
}
```

Bare minimum needed to get rid of a link.